# error installing warzone 2100 0.2.2

Tags: software-installation

When I install warzone2100 0.2.2 I get this

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for dirent.h that defines DIR... yes
checking for library containing opendir... none required
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking malloc.h usability... yes
checking malloc.h presence... yes
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking for memory.h... (cached) yes
checking stddef.h usability... yes
checking stddef.h presence... yes
checking for stddef.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for size_t... yes
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking whether closedir returns void... no
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking for working memcmp... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible realloc... yes
checking whether lstat dereferences a symlink specified with a trailing slash... yes
checking whether stat accepts an empty string... no
checking for vprintf... yes
checking for _doprnt... no
checking for gethostname... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for sqrt... no
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strncasecmp... yes
checking for strrchr... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... (cached) yes
checking for _Bool... (cached) yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for sdl-config... /usr/bin/sdl-config
checking for SDL - version >= 1.1.4... yes
checking for presence of SDL_net... Found SDL_net in path
checking GL/gl.h usability... yes
checking GL/gl.h presence... yes
checking for GL/gl.h... yes
checking for main in -lGL... yes
checking OpenGL... yes
checking AL/al.h usability... yes
checking AL/al.h presence... yes
checking for AL/al.h... yes
checking for main in -lopenal... no
checking for main in -lopenal32... no
checking for main in -lalut... no
checking OpenAL... no
configure: error: OpenAL is currently mandatory
```

how do i install OpenAL?

I typed this but then

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package OpenAL-dev
```

It's called openal not opengl.
Is openal mandatory?
And if it's available how do I install it?

Comment: Yes I know my qeustions are never elaborate

Comment: please I need help getting OpenAL PLEASE!!

Comment: I'm searching a package name for openal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libopenal1 libopenal-dev
```

Also see [Can't make warzone](http://forums.wz2100.net/viewtopic.php?t=410) on the Warzone 2100 forum. Apparently you also need alut (`sudo apt-get install libalut0 libalut-dev`).

Comment: Tried that but still get openal currently mandatory

Comment: Maybe this game uses older versions of openal

Comment: or versions with different names

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: nope still didn't work I think this is made for 2.0 or 3.0 series I'm installing 0.2.2

Comment: Without the `-s` of course. See the link I provided, it is about 0.2.2.

Comment: Is it alut-dev?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libalut0 libalut-dev`

Comment: Both said there already to the latest version when i relaunched ./configure it said openal currently mandatory again!

Comment: checking for main in -lopenal... yes What How?

Comment: mine actually said checking for main in -lopenal... no